# How to change AWS trusted user "sts ExternalId" using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-iam

In my IAM  policy Trust Relationship is showing like below

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::279121212121212:user/ai-s-p57s13"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "xxxxxxxxxxx=2_0vy+PyUFdt728JrFjqeCOau62zU="
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want change Trust Relationship `aws :: sts:ExternalId` id to new values like below using `python` :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::333333333333:user/ai-s-p57s13"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "yyyyyyyyyy=2_0vy+PyUFdt728JrFjqeCOau62zU="
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

using `python` i want to change

i have tried using below code :

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.attach_role_policy(RoleName='testrole', PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::279121212121212:user/testrole')
trust_policy = response['Role']['AssumeRolePolicyDocument']
trust_policy['Statement'][0]['Principal'] ['AWS']= 'arn:aws:iam::279121212121212:user/ai-s-p57s13'
```

Comment: So what is exactly the problem?

Comment: how to change achieve this using python i.e . how can we changing external id value using python code.

Comment: I want to change external id using python code can you please help me on this .

Comment: I see. So what code did you write so far and why it does not work?

Comment: i have added in question section i am getting error like  "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Comment: Where do you run the code? On EC2 instance? Did you attach appropriate role to it? If its your local workstation, did you setup [aws credentails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html#setup-credentials-setting)?

Comment: How did it go? The issue with credentials still persists? If yes, you could make a new question for it, as its different problem than the one reported in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
import json
import boto3

iam = boto3.client('iam')

role_name = "testrole"

# get existing role info
role_info = iam.get_role(RoleName = role_name)

# get trust policy
trust_policy = role_info['Role']['AssumeRolePolicyDocument']

#print(trust_policy)

# get external_id
exiting_external_id = trust_policy['Statement'][0]['Condition']['StringEquals']['sts:ExternalId']

#print(exiting_external_id)

new_prefix='yyyyyyyyyy'

# create new external id
new_external_id = new_prefix + "=" + exiting_external_id.split('=', 1)[1]

#print(new_external_id)

# update the trust policy
trust_policy['Statement'][0]['Condition']['StringEquals']['sts:ExternalId'] = new_external_id

print(trust_policy)

# update the role
response = iam.update_assume_role_policy(
    RoleName=role_name,
    PolicyDocument=json.dumps(trust_policy)
)

print(response)
```

Comment: thanks for Quick reply  after executing above code i am getting error like" botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Comment: @sai I commented on this. You have to setup your aws credentails.

Comment: you mean using access and SECRET key?

Comment: @sai yes. Just follow the link I provided in the other comment.